# What does display.setSegments(&segto, 1, 1); do?

Tags: arduino-uno, display, variables, memory

I am using a TM1637 display for my Arduino Uno. The goal was to just light up one point of the colon in the middle - what seems to be kind of impossible to accomplish. During research I stumbled over the following snippet, which I dont fully understand:

```
  uint8_t segto; 
  int value = 1244; 
  segto = 0x80 | display.encodeDigit((value/100)%10); 
  display.setSegments(&segto, 1, 1);
```

Ok line 1 seems to declare s.th. like a char, an unsigned 8bit integer. Line 2 should be clear.
Line 3: The pipe symbol seems to do a kind of addition - never seen this before. The rest here is also not clear to me - why these strange calculation to pass a value (here 2) to .encodeDigit() ?
Finally line 4: Why is the adress of 'segto' passed to the function instead of just the value?

This all ends up showing a "2:" on the display. I got the snippet from this 'manual': https://robojax.com/learn/arduino/robojax-TM1637_display_manual.pdf

Maybe s.o. can help to light things up a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take the hardest line first.  We'll start from the "inside" outwards.

```
segto = 0x80 | display.encodeDigit((value/100)%10);
```

The innermost bit is:

```
value/100
```

That gives you 12 from 1244.

Then there's modulus 10.

```
12%10
```

That gives you 2 (divide by 10 and return the remainder - 12/10 = 1.2, or 1 remainder 2)

That is then passed through a function that calculates what segments need to be turned on to represent the digit 2. Let's say that's `00110111` in binary, where each bit represents a segment to display.

To that you want to add the colon, which is in the most significant bit's place.  So you set that bit. That's done with the `OR` operator, which in C is `|`. `0x80` is `10000000` in binary.

OR the two values together:

```
00110111
10000000
========
10110111
```

That value is then assigned to the `segto` variable.

I am not familiar with that library, but I would assume that the `setSegments` function is expecting an array of segment settings, a number of digits to apply it to, and maybe a digit offset in the display (at a guess).

In C there is no real difference between using a 1 element array and using a variable and taking its address.

You could just as well have used:

```
uint8_t segto[1];
int value = 1244; 
segto[0] = 0x80 | display.encodeDigit((value/100)%10); 
display.setSegments(segto, 1, 1);
```

If you were doing more than one digit you'd be wanting to use an array anyway.